# How to avoid browser splitting line into two parts when printing to paper

Tags: html, css

I don't know why or how to solve this issue. When I try to print one of my pages, I'm getting this behavior:

[image]

It is a simple HTML page without any plugin, CSS or JavaScript. Has anyone experienced this kind of problem before? How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not your printer settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late to answer but I hope I could help anyone who would face the same issue here.

We could apply it to all elements on our app by adding this code to our general CSS file:

```css
* {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This is the easiest and fastest way to do it.

Comment: 8 years after, thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this a PDF file? If yes, witch component are you using?